# Memory Leak in the Delegate.m

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I have been having trouble with memory leaks, I thought were caused by my uneffeciency.
Ok so I have done the following:

- The 39 UITextViews and UIViews are now "compiled" into just 1 UIView and 1 UITextView. (The fonts are now just followed by 1 UITextViews instead of 39 different)
- The 9 UIViews and 9 MKMapViews are now "compiled"  into just 1 UIView and 1 MKMapView.
  This is the biggest part of the Application and therefor it definitely should have gotten rid of the problem, but then I noticed this.

This memory leak has been causing the problem almost since day one of my project. What can I do to fix this problem in the delegate.m, the heart of the Application?

Comment: Have you considered ARC? Update your code to use ARC and your problem is most likely solved.

Also, some log details would be awesome!

Comment: YES, I have used ARC and I did not have an impact upon the Memory leak.

Comment: Then I doubt you have a memory leak... I guess you might have a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or similar. Yet, without the log I cannot help you. Update your question with the log. Also, enable Zombie, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

leave all it just implement a custom cell in which make a text field and in another one make uitextview.

for more read this tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/